# HTML5 Form Text Placeholders - Do they have a CSS pseudo-class?

Tags: forms, html, css, placeholder

Reading an article about HTML5, it occurs to me that while placeholders are incredibly useful in form usability, if they can not be targeted with CSS without javascript, they really are a baby step.

So can I target the placeholder in CSS to look differently from inputted text?

Comment: Is there a way to get "placeholder" behavior at all without JavaScript?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: @Pointy Yes, as Mild Fuzz says, it's in HTML5. [This, for example](http://jsfiddle.net/jnzhe/), already works in Chrome.

Comment: @Jon Good find; I've tagged that older question with "pseudo-class" now to make it easier to find; strikes me that's the important term that's missing from that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Webkit uses a ::-webkit-input-placeholder pseudoelement. Moz uses a :-moz-placeholder pseudoclass.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. Is there a variant for IE9 ?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support placeholder.

Comment: You can probably assume ::-ms-input-placeholder and ::placeholder for future compatibility.

Comment: No you can't. You'd be taking a gamble. None of these is standardized, and they're not even compatible with each other. There's nothing indicating that IE will adopt WebKit's approach or that the standard will be a mix of both.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
I assume you have got something like this in your HTML

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

The corresponding css would be

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: blue;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: blue;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: blue;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: blue;
}
input:placeholder { 
  color: blue;
}
```

I also encourage you taking a look at

```
input:placeholder-shown {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

This is a good [resource](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder).